# Issue with MVC architecture in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

I was going through the concept of MVC in PHP.

I found a sample code to Display HELLO WORLD.

Since I am very new to this, I have no idea how to implement the MVC architecture for Radio active buttons or any other buttons which takes the users input and stores it in database.

The sample code which I found to display Hello world is as follows

```
<?php
class Model {
    public $text;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->text = 'Hello world!';
    }
}


class View {
    protected $model;
    protected $controller;

    public function __construct(Controller $controller, Model $model) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function output() {
        return $this->model->text ;
    }

}


class Controller {
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}

$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);
echo $view->output();
?>
```

I have been searching for the answer on the web for a long time but with no success . :(

So I would appreciate any help on this .IT WOULD BE REALLY WONDERFUL IF YOU COULD PROVIDE ME WITH THE SAMPLE CODE FOR THIS .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: If you can't use a framework like CI or Yii, this sounds like homework.  Either way, the code you posted works, and you are asking for something else (radio button inputs).  What have you tried to do to implement it, and could you post that instead?

Comment: @Sarke as I said I am very new to MVC as well as PHP :(. So I do not have much idea regarding this . So if you could post me a very simple Radio button input using mvc code I could take it from there and work on it .

Comment: Where did you found that code? Why do you take that code if it does not what you need it to do? Where exactly are you hitting a roadblock? Do you really expect somebody here to explain you OOP and MVC in one answer? Please elaborate so your question can be actually answered. And welcome to SO.

Comment: @hakre Well I was expecting someone would post a very simple code which makes the user enter data on a radio active button using MVC

Comment: What do you mean by "implement radio active buttons using mvc"? MVC is a design pattern. Your question kinda makes no sense. Also, **what have you tried ?**

Answer (score 1):

suggest going through and watching some codeigniter tutorials i know its a framework but will help you to understand the concept a lot better.

They explain mvc very well.

Also take a look at this

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-login-system-for-a-simple-website/

Comment: Sure Matt . ThankYou . Let me just go through this link now . :)

Comment: and if your allowed to use a framework use codeigniter and take a look at this 

http://formigniter.org/

will be insanely helpful generating the necessary models, controllers and views for the forms and u can just include session on top.

Comment: I Wish I could have used the frameworks , but unfortunately I am not allowed to use them :( :( .

Comment: still worth generating it in formigniter , its still going to be very similar code.

Comment: Let me just give it a try . Thanks Matt

Comment: Here's a free advice: avoid Nettuts. They have pretty presentation for bad practices. I downloaded the source from that link and took a quick view. Here are the conclusions: it recommends to use unsalted MD5. That is not acceptable in 2012.

Answer (score -1):

You should better try some MVC Framework like CodeIgniter which is very simple to understand and use.

Comment: I wish I could have done that :( but I need to find a way to make this work without Codeignitor or any other frameworks

Comment: It would be great to give comments while giving -ve vote, and possible correct solution also.